# importing data from mysql

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark, dst

I am trying to import data from `mysql` to `pyspark`. I am able to get the data from `mysql` to `pyspark` as a data frame. But the data frame shows wrong times for timestamp columns during `daylightsavings` time.

Below is data for a table that got data during Daylight Savings tTme.

**MySQL Data**

```
id  Package_time            System_time             PACKAGE GROUP                               
1   3/12/2017 2:19:51 AM    2017-03-11 18:13:43.577 TEST_1  STATUS                              
2   3/12/2017 2:19:53 AM    2017-03-11 18:13:43.577 TEST_1  ALARM                               
3   3/12/2017 2:19:53 AM    2017-03-11 18:13:43.577 TEST_1  ALARM                               
4   3/12/2017 2:19:53 AM    2017-03-11 18:13:43.577 TEST_1  ALARM                               
5   3/12/2017 2:19:54 AM    2017-03-11 18:13:44.611 TEST_1  STATUS
```

**PySpark data**

```
id  Package_time            System_time             PACKAGE GROUP                               
1   3/12/2017 3:19:51 AM    2017-03-11 18:13:43.577 TEST_1  STATUS
2   3/12/2017 3:19:53 AM    2017-03-11 18:13:43.577 TEST_1  ALARM
3   3/12/2017 3:19:53 AM    2017-03-11 18:13:43.577 TEST_1  ALARM
4   3/12/2017 3:19:53 AM    2017-03-11 18:13:43.577 TEST_1  ALARM
5   3/12/2017 3:19:54 AM    2017-03-11 18:13:44.611 TEST_1  STATUS
```

I want the `pyspark` data frame to have data same as in `mysql` table. How can I achieve my result.

What changes do I need to make to ensure that both the data are same.

**Datatypes of columns:**

```
id int
package_time timestamp
system_time timestamp
package string
group strimg
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us the datatypes of your time columns.

Comment: @O.Jones I have added the datatypes to the question. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! You have `TIMESTAMP` data types for your datestamp values. These are stored in UTC in your database. They're translated to local time according to the current time zone setting when they're retrieved.

You can get them all in UTC by using this SQL command before you run your query.

```
 SET time_zone='UTC';
```

If you want all your datestamps shown Pacific local time, with daylight savings time taken into account, you can use this:

```
SET time_zone = 'America/Vancouver';
```

If you want all your datestamps in Pacific STANDARD time, without daylight savings time taken into account, you can use this:

```
SET time_zone='-08:00';
```

Comment: your solution will work in `mysql` but I don't think this will work in `spark`

Comment: @O.Jones How can we set `time_zone` to take in to consideration the daylight savings time